# Expression of type Any Doesn't conform to expected type sql.DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, try-catch

I have the following functions to read files and retries when short timeouts occur:

```
// read logic
def read(loc){ Try {spark.read.parquet(loc)} }

// retry for m times
def df(floc):DataFrame={
    read(floc) match {
      case Success(df) => { df }
      case Failure(exception) => {
        if ( c < m ) {       // c & m declared, c is incremented after each failure&retry
         Thread.sleep(100000L)
         read(floc)
   }} //Expression of type Any Doesn't  conform to expected type sql.DataFrame
}}

val df:DataFrame = df("FILE_location")
```

The return type expected doesn't match in Failure case. Any suggestions on where am I going wrong or any better way of doing this. Appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: add `if(c<m) .. else null` to make your code compile

Comment: If I do that, I get `Expression of type Try[sql.DataFrame] doesn't confirm to expected type sql.DataFrame` since read(loc) returns `Try[sql.DataFrame]`